# specify classpath for plugin inside apply method

Tags: gradle

How to specify classpath for custom `gradle` plugin inside class, that implements interface `Plugin`?

```
class TaskPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.task('task') << {
            println 'simple task'
        }

    }
}
```

I saw something similar there

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6277a4dc70fbeea83c111e75c95ba851d1e56ffc/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/WarPlugin.java#L25

However I don't know how to apply it for my case. Specifically I want to use both `test` and `main` sourcesets.

I want to get rid of `classpath` dependencies, related to my project. Because I have the same dependencies in `dependencies` and in `buildscript { dependencies {`

Every time I add plugin I have to add `classpath` dependencies, which that plugin is using.

```
apply plugin: 'my-plugin'
task {
     ... do something
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDirs dir('.')
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("my-group:my-plugin:my-version")
        classpath ("dependency:dependency:dependency")
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I specify basic `dependencies` (not inside `buildscript`) I may have the same dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile ("dependency:dependency:dependency")
}
```

Sometimes I need some compiled project dependencies `compile project(":my-project")` which I have to specify using `classpath files("path to compiled")`.

How to adjust plugin implementation to remove those `dependency` duplicates? Like for example if I declared dependency using `compile` or `runtime` - plugin will know about it and there is no need to declare dependency in classpath explicitly.

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem a little bit? Also the linked resource points to import stmt?

Comment: @Opal Done. #25 had no point - It seems It was left in my url.